# NTriplesParser extract textual value from string

Tags: dotnetrdf

I am using dotnetrdf and trying to parse some triples with NTriplesParser. I have my own handler RobHandler in which I process each triple in turn.

```
public class RobHandler : BaseRdfHandler
{
    protected override bool HandleTripleInternal(Triple t)
    {
        string predicateUrl = ((BaseUriNode)(t.Predicate)).Uri.AbsoluteUri;
        string value = t.Object.ToString();
    }
}
```

This works fine but I want to get the object minus the language. My objects look like "Lincoln"@en. I could obviously write some code to remove the @en bit, but I'd rather use some library code rather than my own that hard-coded strings like @en. To do this I think I need to create a LiteralNode but there doesn't seem to be a way to get from a string which is what I have (my variable value) to a LiteralNode.

How can I extract just the  textual value from an object string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually I think I have the answer myself:

```
  if (t.Object.NodeType == NodeType.Literal)
  {
      var node = (ILiteralNode)t.Object;
  }
```

Comment: Yep, note it is generally better to cast to the interfaces e.g. `IUriNode` and `ILiteralNode` rather than the concrete types